# Finding all usages of a value (Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, constants, abstract-syntax-tree, code-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
// constants.ts

export const CONSTANTS = {
  CONFIG: {
    PREFIX: 'dot-'
  }
};
```

```
// component.ts -- Illustrating all the different ways the constant value `dot-` is used.
import {CONSTANTS} from './constants';

class Component1 {
  config = CONSTANTS.CONFIG;

  method1 () {
    return this.config.PREFIX + 'some-text';
  }

  method2 () {
    return CONSTANTS.CONFIG.PREFIX + 'some-text';
  }

  method3 () {
    const prefix = 'dot-';
    return prefix.length;
  }

  method4 (prefix, suffix) {
    return prefix + suiffix;
  }

  method5 () {
    return this.method4('dot-', 'com');
  }
}
```

I want to be able to detect the usage of `dot-` in all the ways possible. I am planning to approach this by using a combination of a webpack loader (analyze TS files) and a plugin (analyze compiled JS files).

Loader Steps:

- `Step 1.1: Cache all constant values` - To detect the value declared in the global constants file(s), and create a cache of all values.
- `Step 1.2: Detect literal usage` - To detect usage of literals ('dot-') used in the code (other than the constant files).

Plugin Steps:

- `Step 2.1: Walk through AST` - Visit each node to detect assignment of constants to other variables (either from the constant declaration or as literal)
- `Step 2.2: Walk through AST (--again??)` - Visit each node to detect the usage of the value from the output from `Step 1.1` and `Step 2.1`)

P.S.: This is an Angular project.

Any suggestions on this approach? Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a static (build-time) count of all `dot-` strings or a dynamic (runtime) count? Anyway visiting an AST is not always so easy, you should keep trace of many things like all the assignments and function calls: eg. `var c = CONSTANTS.CONFIG.PREFIX;` and then you can use `c` bilions of times...

Comment: Static count is enough. I want this to be part of application build.

Comment: I guess you could define a type in typescript (like `type DOT = 'dot-';`) and check for it with the ts compiler API. Maybe this would be the fastest way to prevent check every sinigle assignment

Comment: That is a good idea. Unfortunately, I have several strings like that I need to test for. :/